# What is the MVC Futures Library?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-futures

On Stack Overflow, I've seen a few people referring to the [MVC Futures library](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/24471)

What is this project? How do I use it? Where is the documentation?

Comment: For reference the location of the project is currently:

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24471

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Check [Eilon Lipton's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2009/03/03/asp-net-mvc-release-candidate-2-i-declare-myself-to-be-declarative.aspx) :

> In this blog post I'll introduce you
>   to a feature that's not even part of
>   the main ASP.NET MVC download. It's
>   part of the separate MVC Futures
>   download, **which includes prototypes of
>   features that we're thinking of
>   including in a future version of
>   ASP.NET MVC**.

Answer (score 23):

There is no documentation because it is very early prototype work. We do post the source code so if you're really interested, you can figure it out. Over time, we'll start to blog about it and provide samples. Right now, our focus is on the main product. We post the futures to provide a way for those who really want to dig into the source to provide feedback on what we're thinking about for the future.

Comment: Is this still the case?  I can't find any documentation about what's even available in this library?  I found people using @html.Serialize but cannot find any information about to actually use this.  It does not bind the values on post backs to my ViewModel.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this blog. It highlights areas of the MVC Future

http://msmvps.com/blogs/luisabreu/archive/tags/MVC/default.aspx

Comment: fyi that link is broken