# DataAnnotations jQuery validation in asp.net mvc 2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I trying to use jQuery validation plugin with DataAnnotations in asp.net mvc 2 final. Now I'm using MicrosoftMvcValidation.js and it works. But I can't find way to work with jQuery validation. I read about MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js. But I think that it is obsolete. How can I use DataAnnotations with jQuery validation plugin?

Answer (score 1):

**Right-on!**  I have exactly this same question.

I had typed up a very nice long reply with all sorts of embedded hyperlinks for you, but stackoverflow won't let me post it for you because I don't have enough reputation.  Kinda chicken-and-egg...

So, look here:
http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742

Shannon

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using the [Mvc Futures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614224/what-is-the-mvc-futures-library) but below is a remark [in another forum](http://forums.asp.net/p/1544798/3773403.aspx) from a *Senior developer on the ASP.NET MVC team*:

"We went down the path with jQuery Validation originally and found it didn't quite fit our needs, so we stopped development on it and moved it into Futures. It's not something that we support and is only included because it was present in interim builds of MVC 2. It will definitely need a lot of work to be usable."